# Unable to install packages -- Pycharm -- Python.exec path not working

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I am trying to install packages to use in a python program and am unable to install anything. Included below are screen shots showing the interpreter selected, the path of that interpreter, and the error message I receive. Please let me know what I am missing.

[image: Interpreter and its path]

[image: Error Message]

I've been looking around at other people's problems like this and nothing seems to fit my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error seems like you do not have a stable connection to the pypi. The standard recommendation would be to "Make sure you are connected to the internet, Pycharm is allowed through the firewall and that your proxy (if you are behind one) allows access to this url address."

Now that is not very helpful so if this issue is happening over a single package, you can simply download the python wheel from [the beautifulsoup's project page](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/#files) and install it manually by running `pip install downloaded_whl_file.whl` in the Pycharm's terminal (make sure that the environment is right!)

Lastly, you might be able to get around it by using a pip proxy through `pip install beautifulsoup4 --proxy http://some-proxy.com`

I hope that the above can help you get through your issue!